# twitter post in powerpoint

Tags: twitter, powerpoint, keynote

Im trying to integrate a twitter post into my Powerpoint/keynote presentation and I cant, I want to find a better way than just a screenshot, which would mean having to photoshop off the edges and put a drop shadow to look good (last part not so important). any help?